# Nokogiri condition based on attribute value

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I'm attempting to potentially parse two XML files with Nokogiri, which is based on an attribute value existing.  The problem is that my initial conditional is always returning true, even if the node doesn't exist at the `xpath`.  I think I've done everything right, but obviously I haven't.

Here are my two XML files:

**dnsrecon_output.xml (typical file output)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<records>
    <record ns_server="192.168.1.1" type="info" zone_transfer="failed"/>
    <record ns_server="192.168.1.2" type="info" zone_transfer="failed"/>
    <record address="192.168.1.1" mname="ns1.mynetwork.local" type="SOA"/>
    <record Version="9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.37.rc1.el6_7.5" address="192.168.1.1" recursive="True" target="ns1.mynetwork.local" type="NS"/>
    <record Version="9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.37.rc1.el6_7.5" address="192.168.1.2" recursive="True" target="ns2.mynetwork.local" type="NS"/>
    <record address="192.168.1.3" name="web.local" type="A"/>
</records>
```

**dnsrecon_brute.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<records>
    <record address="192.168.1.3" name="dev.web.local" type="A"/>
    <record name="ftp.web.local" target="dev.web.local" type="CNAME"/>
    <record address="192.168.1.4" name="git.web.local" type="A"/>
    <record address="192.168.1.5" name="ops.web.local" type="A"/>
    <record address="192.168.1.6" name="whm.web.local" type="A"/>
    <record address="192.168.1.7" name="www.web.local" type="A"/>
</records>
```

However, if `zone_transfer=success` the output will look like this...

**dnsrecon_output_xfer.xml (just to show what I'm trying to match)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<records>
    <record ns_server="192.168.1.2" type="info" zone_transfer="success"/>
    <record address="192.168.1.2" mname="ns" type="SOA" zone_server="192.168.1.2"/>
    <record address="192.168.1.2" target="ns1.network.local" type="NS" zone_server="192.168.1.2"/>
    <record address="192.168.1.100" name="win.network.local" type="A" zone_server="192.168.1.2"/>
    <record address="192.168.1.2" name="ns1.network.local" type="A" zone_server="192.168.1.2"/>
    <record address="192.168.1.2" mname="ns1.network.local" type="SOA"/>
</records>
```

And here's my Nokogiri parsing.  Mainly I want to check to see if the `zone_transfer=success` exists, if it doesn't move on to the `*_brute.xml` file:

```
document = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("dnsrecon_output.xml"))

document.remove_namespaces!

# Strictly for Zone transfers
if document.xpath("//records//record[@zone_transfer='success']")
  puts "Zone Transfer Successful ... YIKES!!!"
  document.xpath("//records//record[@type='A']").each do |record|
    # change the output here to match what we need it to...
    puts "#{record.at_xpath("@address")} - #{record.at_xpath("@name")}"
  end
else
  puts "No zone transfers... moving to brute"
  document2 = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("dnsrecon_brute.xml"))
  document2.remove_namespaces!

  document2.xpath("//records//record[@type='A' or @type='CNAME']").each do |record|
    puts "#{record.at_xpath("@address")} - #{record.at_xpath("@name")}"
  end
end
```

As you'll note, I'm initially parsing the `dnsrecon_output.xml` file, which has the `zone_transfer="failed"` in the record tag. However, my output in my console is:

```
Zone Transfer Successful ... YIKES!!!
192.168.1.3 - web.local
```

And never runs the `else` portion, which is should.  Where have I gone wrong with the attribute value checking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your check returns an empty `Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet` which is truthy.

Either read the attribute and compare its value:

```
if document.xpath("//records//record/@zone_transfer").first.value == 'success'
    ...
```

Note that this will only work if the xpath matches at least one element (so it wont work for the "brute" file).

or add a `any?` to get a boolean return:

```
if document.xpath("//records//record[@zone_transfer='success']").any?
    ...
```

Comment: Your fist conditional won't work for an empty array: `first()` returns nil and you can't call `value()` on nil.

Comment: use `document.at` to get an element or nil

Answer (score 0):

```
x = document.xpath("//records//record[@zone_transfer='success']")
p x

--output:--
[]
```

and:

```
if []
  puts %q{It's true!}
end

--output:--
It's true.
```

The only values that evaluate to false in ruby are `false` itself and `nil`.  Empty arrays, empty hashes, blank strings, `0`, etc. are all true.

Instead, you can do something like this:

```
if document.xpath("//records//record[@zone_transfer='success']").empty?
  puts "no matching elements"
  #got to next xml file
else
  puts "found matches"
  #do your other xpath search
end

--output:--
no matching elements
```

Comment: The xpath query does not return an empty array but an empty ```NodeSet``` (which does not make a difference in the if clause though)

Comment: @pascalbetz, *The Node methods xpath and css actually return a NodeSet, which acts very much like an array...*